# Most efficient way to create the Data.Set of all pairs of elements in a Set?

Tags: performance, haskell

Given an arbitrary set holding an arbitrary number of elements of arbitrary type, e.g.

```
mySet1 = Set.fromList [1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
mySet2 = Set.fromList ["a","b","c","d"]
```

or

```
mySet3 = Set.fromList [A, B, C, D]
```

for some data constructors A, B, C, D, ...

What is the computationally most efficient way to generate the set of all unordered pairs of elements is the given set? I.e.

```
setPairs mySet1 == Set.fromList [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

or

```
setPairs mySet2 == fromList [ ("a","b")
                            , ("a","c")
                            , ("a","d")
                            , ("b","c")
                            , ("b","d")
                            , ("c","d") ]
```

or

```
setPairs mySet2 == fromList [ (A,B)
                            , (A,C)
                            , (A,D)
                            , (B,C)
                            , (B,D)
                            , (C,D) ]
```

---

My initial naive guess would be:

```
setPairs s = fst $ Set.fold
    (\e (pairAcc, elementsLeft) ->
        ( Set.fold
              (\e2 pairAcc2 ->
                  Set.insert (e2, e) pairAcc2
              ) pairAcc $ Set.delete e elementsLeft
        , Set.delete e elementsLeft )
    ) (Set.empty, s) s
```

but surely that cannot be the best solution?

Comment: The easiest way to think of this is in terms of list comprehensions, where the answer almost writes itself...

Comment: Yes, I can see this being done with sets but it likely wouldn't be elegant in the same way a filterM or a list comprehension solution would be. Is conversion to list an option or does the list waypoint make the solution unworkable for you?

Comment: @Erik Hinton: A conversion to list would be alright, if it provides the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Benchmarking might prove me wrong, but my suspicion is that there's no win in staying in the set representation. You're going to need O(n^2) regardless, because that's the size of the output. The key advantage would be producing your list such that you could use a call to `S.fromDistinctAscList` such that it only costs O(n) to build the set itself.

The following is pretty clean, preserves a fair amount of sharing, and is generally the simplest, most straightforward and intuitive solution I can imagine.

```
pairs s = S.fromDistinctAscList . concat $ zipWith zip (map (cycle . take 1) ts) (drop 1 ts)
   where ts = tails $ S.toList s
```

---

**Edit**

Shorter/clearer (not sure performancewise, but probably as good/better):

```
pairs s = S.fromDistinctAscList [(x,y) | (x:xt) <- tails (S.toList s), y <- xt]
```

Comment: My instinct is to agree with you. The only concern would be if there was some great overhead in the `toList`. I doubt, though, that it would be terribly expensive.

Comment: `toList` is defined as a fold, which is defined straightforwardly.

Comment: I'd imagine that this solution uses less intermediate memory than other solutions, because it is streaming insofar as it can be. The memory used by the final set is, of course, going to cost the same regardless.

Comment: I did some benchmarking. Both solutions given above are by far the fastest of the solutions given so far. The shorter version using list comprehension is faster for large sets but slower for small sets. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to generate all sets. `replicateM` from Control.Monad helps with it.

```
λ> replicateM 2 [1..4]
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4]]
```

Then you need to filter pairs, where second element is greater than first

```
λ> filter (\[x,y] -> x < y)  $ replicateM 2 [1 .. 4]
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

Finally, you need to convert every list in a tuple

```
λ> map (\[x,y] -> (x,y)) $ filter (\[x,y] -> x < y)  $ replicateM 2 [1 .. 4]
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

Then we can formulate it into function `pairs`:

```
import Data.Set
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

mySet = Data.Set.fromList [1,2,3,4]

--setOfPairs = Data.Set.fromList [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
setOfPairs = Data.Set.fromList $ pairs mySet

pairs :: Ord a => Set a -> [(a,a)]
pairs x = Data.List.map (\[x,y] -> (x,y)) $ Data.List.filter (\[x,y] -> x < y) $ replicateM 2 $ toList x
```

So, if I got you question right, you can use `pairs mySet`, where pairs generate the list of all unordered pairs of `mySet`.

Is it what you want?

**UPD**:

[List comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension) could be more clear and fast technique to create such sublists, so here is another instance of `pairs`:

```
pairs :: Ord a => Set a -> [(a,a)]
pairs set = [(x,y) | let list = toList set, x <- list, y <- list, x < y]
```

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate answer. Unfortunately that does not work on a set of strings since they aren't in Ord.

Comment: Show some examples what are you expecting from `setOfPairs`.

Comment: Sorry, of course String is in Ord as is any data type of elements in a set. My apologies. But is the conversion to lists really the fastest way to do this?

Comment: I'm just a beginner and do not have such experience to comparing some algorithms and data types. All that I can say - conversion to list is the simplest way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a first stab at a solution using conversion back and forth to a list. Again, I am not sure this is the fastest way to do this but I do know that iteration over sets it's not terribly efficient.

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Set as S

pairs :: S.Set String -> S.Set (String,String)
pairs s = S.fromList $ foldl' (\st e -> (zip l e) ++ st) [] ls
          where (l:ls) = tails $ S.toList s
```

By folding zip over the tails, you get a nice and efficient way to create the set of unordered pairs. However, instinct encourages me that there may be a monadic filterM or foldM solution that's even more elegant. I will keep thinking.

[EDIT]

So here is what should be [but is not on account of the size of the powerset] a faster solution that does not require a toList.

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

pairs :: (Ord a) => S.Set a -> S.Set (a,a)
pairs s = S.fromList $ foldl two [] $ F.foldlM (\st e -> [[e]++st,st]) [] s
          where two st (x:xa:[]) = (x,xa) : st
                two st _ = st
```

Uses the power-set solution over monadic lists to build the powerset and then filter out the pairs. I can go into more detail if necessary.

Comment: In a quick benchmarking the solution with toList is very very much faster than the one without toList. Since the size of the powerset grows exponentially with the size of the given set, so does the time consumption of this solution. Cheers,

Comment: Ahh, excellent point. When in doubt, always trust the benchmark. Cheers,